# Android EditText Value Error?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm testing out some stuff on android as a beginner and was trying to grab value entered in a EditText when a button was clicked , then compare it to a string value that I defined inside the class, then use if (EditText == stringDefined) else () , but my code always jumps on the else part even if the correct text is entered, any help is appreciated. Here is the code :

```
Button mButton;
EditText mEdit1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    final String user = "admin";

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_login);
    mEdit1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String userEntered = mEdit1.getText().toString().trim();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Success.class);
                    if(userEntered == user){
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder errAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                        errAlert.setTitle("Wrong Credentials");
                        errAlert.setMessage("Wrong username");
                        errAlert.setCancelable(true);
                        errAlert.show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Where do you define mEdit2? I'm only seeing mEdit1

Comment: @TylerOlson - i have two EditTexts in my code actually and I removed one to make it simpler in the question , my bad there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use equals method :

```
if(userEntered.equals(user)){
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Note: '== operator' compares the object references, not the content

Comment: thank you that worked fine, I always worked with C and C# and the == operator worked fine there most of the times didnt know in java theres a .equal function

Answer (score 0):

`==` is used to compare primitive types and `equals()` method of `java.lang.String` class compares contents.